# How can I combine this border with my slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, I have created this rotating border and slideshow. I would like the rotating border to go around the slideshow, however, I have not figured out a way on completing this task. I have tried moving the div's from the border to the slideshow code, but the border gets all messed up. How can I implement my border so it goes around the slideshow? Thanks. Here is my code.

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Border */
@keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}
.rainbow {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2rem;
}
.rainbow::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    left: -50%;
    top: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    background-color: #399953;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 50%, 50% 50%;
    background-position: 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#399953, #399953), linear-gradient(#fbb300, #fbb300), linear-gradient(#d53e33, #d53e33), linear-gradient(#377af5, #377af5);
    animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
}
.rainbow::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 6px;
    top: 6px;
    width: calc(100% - 12px);
    height: calc(100% - 12px);
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
/* Slideshow */
.slidershow {
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.middle {
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.navigation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: flex;
}
.bar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #3F69CA;
    margin: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.bar:hover {
    background: #3F69CA;
}
input[name="r"] {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slides {
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.slidess {
    width: 20%;
    transition: 0.6s;
}
.slidess>h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
    color: rgb(24, 23, 23);
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    z-index: 2;
}
.slides .slidess:hover>h2 {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.slidess img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#r1:checked~.s1 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#r2:checked~.s1 {
    margin-left: -20%;
}
#r3:checked~.s1 {
    margin-left: -40%;
}
#r4:checked~.s1 {
    margin-left: -60%;
}
#r1:checked~.navigation [for="r1"] {
    background: #fff
}
#r2:checked~.navigation [for="r2"] {
    background: #fff
}
#r3:checked~.navigation [for="r3"] {
    background: #fff
}
#r4:checked~.navigation [for="r4"] {
    background: #fff
}
@media (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 899px) {
    .slidershow {
        width: 300px;
        height: 201px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        position: relative;
        top: 90px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--Border-->
    <div class="rainbow"></div>
  <!--Slideshow-->
    <div id="outside">
        <div class="slidershow middle">
            <div class="slides">
                <input checked id="r1" name="r" type="radio"> <input id="r2" name="r" type="radio"> <input id="r3" name="r" type="radio"> <input id="r4" name="r" type="radio">
                <div class="navigation">
                    <label class="bar" for="r1"></label> <label class="bar" for="r2"></label> <label class="bar" for="r3"></label> <label class="bar" for="r4"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="slidess s1">
                <h2>Slide 1.</h2><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/842711/pexels-photo-842711.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"></div>
                <div class="slidess">
                <h2>Slide 2.</h2><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1643409/pexels-photo-1643409.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"></div>
                <div class="slidess">
                <h2>Slide 3.</h2><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2246476/pexels-photo-2246476.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"></div>
                <div class="slidess">
                <h2>Slide 4.</h2><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1452701/pexels-photo-1452701.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Border */
@keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}
.rainbow {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 6px;
}
.rainbow::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    left: -50%;
    top: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    background-color: #399953;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 50%, 50% 50%;
    background-position: 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#399953, #399953), linear-gradient(#fbb300, #fbb300), linear-gradient(#d53e33, #d53e33), linear-gradient(#377af5, #377af5);
    animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
}
.rainbow::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 6px;
    top: 6px;
    width: calc(100% - 12px);
    height: calc(100% - 12px);
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
/* Slideshow */
.slidershow {
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.middle {
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.navigation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: flex;
}
.bar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #3F69CA;
    margin: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.bar:hover {
    background: #3F69CA;
}
input[name="r"] {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slides {
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.slidess {
    width: 20%;
    transition: 0.6s;
}
.slidess>h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
    color: rgb(24, 23, 23);
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    z-index: 2;
}
.slides .slidess:hover>h2 {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.slidess img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#r1:checked~.s1 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#r2:checked~.s1 {
    margin-left: -20%;
}
#r3:checked~.s1 {
    margin-left: -40%;
}
#r4:checked~.s1 {
    margin-left: -60%;
}
#r1:checked~.navigation [for="r1"] {
    background: #fff
}
#r2:checked~.navigation [for="r2"] {
    background: #fff
}
#r3:checked~.navigation [for="r3"] {
    background: #fff
}
#r4:checked~.navigation [for="r4"] {
    background: #fff
}
@media (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 899px) {
    .slidershow {
        width: 300px;
        height: 201px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        position: relative;
        top: 100px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="rainbow">
               <div id="outside">
                    <div class="slidershow middle">
                        <div class="slides">
                            <input checked id="r1" name="r" type="radio"> <input id="r2" name="r" type="radio"> <input id="r3" name="r" type="radio"> <input id="r4" name="r" type="radio">
                            <div class="navigation">
                                <label class="bar" for="r1"></label> <label class="bar" for="r2"></label> <label class="bar" for="r3"></label> <label class="bar" for="r4"></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slidess s1">
                            <h2>Slide 1.</h2><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/842711/pexels-photo-842711.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"></div>
                            <div class="slidess">
                            <h2>Slide 2.</h2><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1643409/pexels-photo-1643409.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"></div>
                            <div class="slidess">
                            <h2>Slide 3.</h2><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2246476/pexels-photo-2246476.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"></div>
                            <div class="slidess">
                            <h2>Slide 4.</h2><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1452701/pexels-photo-1452701.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Hey @RaymondNelson this is my whatsapp no. if you hve need any help then contact me .. +918200808100